# Involutive automorphism of simple Lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras, involutions, symmetric-spaces

Let $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{k}+\mathfrak{p}$ be a Cartan decomposition for a noncompact real simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ corresponding to a Cartan involution $\theta$, where $\mathfrak{k}$ is the maximal compact subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$. Suppose that $\sigma$ is another involutive automorphism of $\mathfrak{g}$ such that $\sigma\theta=\theta\sigma$. Then $\sigma$ preserves the Cartan decomposition, and $\sigma|_\mathfrak{k}:\mathfrak{k}\rightarrow\mathfrak{k}$. By the classification for symmetric pairs, it seems true that $\sigma|_\mathfrak{k}$ is never an identity map, but how to prove this fact uniformly?

In other words, there is no (non-Cartan) involutive automorphism $\sigma$ of a noncompact real simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ such that the subalgebra $\mathfrak{g}^\sigma$ of the fixed points under the action of $\sigma$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ contains a maximal compact subalgebra. How to prove it?

Comment: Crossposted to MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362158/involutive-automorphism-of-simple-lie-algebra